# How to remove .kotlin_metadata in apk

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

When I build android application with kotlin, apk size is increased.

Inside the apk, many .kotlin_metadata files in both kotlin/ kotlinx/ folders.

Is there any way to remove them from my apk?

Answer (score 4):

Add the following line in your `build.gradle` file.

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude '/kotlin_metadata/**'

    }
```

https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Comment: Using kotlin 1.3 my metadata's are at /kotlin/*/.kotlin_metadata, for axample collections, coroutines, reflect, etc